# LuaLaTex never finishes compiling with luatexja package

Tags: luatex, compiling, chinese, luatexja

I have a problem with the package luatexja. It is my first time dealing with non-latin characters in latex. Here is an example of my code:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
%\setmainjfont{FandolSong}

\begin{document}
    \title{Test}
    \author{Author name}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}

    Test 中文

\end{document}
```

If I try to compile this with lualatex it never finishes compiling. It shows the following error messages:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 21.8) (format=lualatex 2021.12.1)  23 MAR 2022 11:02
 restricted system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**mwe.tex
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2021-05-21 3.18 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2021-05-20 2.74 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/jgruenwald/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2021-05-20.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2021-05-20.
lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.116
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/jgruenwald/AppData/Local/M
iKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' at position 1 in `post_linebreak_filt
er'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 4
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' at position 1 in `input_level_string'.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook-3.34.sty"
Package: scrlfile-hook-3.34 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX h
ooks)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty"
Package: scrlogo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
Applying: [2021/05/01] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line 252.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Usage of raw or classic option list on input line
 368.
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box50
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 135.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrartcl)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 224
2.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/jgruenwald/AppData/Lo
cal/MiKTeX/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2021/11/13 v3.35 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count179
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1743.
)
\c@part=\count180
\c@section=\count181
\c@subsection=\count182
\c@subsubsection=\count183
\c@paragraph=\count184
\c@subparagraph=\count185
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4852.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4852.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl)           for `\part on input line 4860.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4870.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4870.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4880.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4880.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4891.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4891.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4901.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4901.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip59
\belowcaptionskip=\skip60
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box51
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6076.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip61
\c@figure=\count186
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6091.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@table=\count187
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6258.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/addons/luatexja-fontspec.sty"
Package: luatexja-fontspec 2020-09-14 fontspec support of LuaTeX-ja

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2021-08-27 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def"
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count188
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package: l3keys2e 2021-08-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.sty"
Package: luatexja 2022-03-11 Japanese Typesetting with Lua(La)TeX

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-core.sty"
Package: luatexja-core 2022-01-12 Core of LuaTeX-ja

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty"
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty"
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count189
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable12
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable13
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks17
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks18
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks19
)
\XKV@depth=\count190
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count191
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/everyhook/everyhook.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/svn-prov/svn-prov.sty"
Package: svn-prov 2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
)
Package: everyhook 2014/11/26 v1.2 (SVN Rev: 12)\ Hooks for low level TeX every
X primitives.
\everypar=\toks20
\frozen@everymath=\toks21
\frozen@everydisplay=\toks22
\everyhbox=\toks23
\everyvbox=\toks24
\everycr=\toks25
)
\ltjlineendcomment=\count192
\ltj@dimen@zw=\dimen139
\ltj@dimen@zh=\dimen140
\ltj@dimen@jQ=\dimen141
\ltj@icflag=\attribute5
\ltj@curjfnt=\attribute6
\ltj@curtfnt=\attribute7
\ltj@charclass=\attribute8
\ltj@charcode=\attribute9
\ltj@autospc=\attribute10
\ltj@autoxspc=\attribute11
\ltj@yablshift=\attribute12
\ltj@ykblshift=\attribute13
\ltj@tablshift=\attribute14
\ltj@tkblshift=\attribute15
\jfam=\attribute16
\ltj@vert@ori=\attribute17
\ltj@dir=\attribute18
\ltj@@japanese=\language2
\ltj@tempcnta=\count193
\ltj@kcat0=\attribute19
\ltj@kcat1=\attribute20
\ltj@kcat2=\attribute21
\ltj@kcat3=\attribute22
\ltj@kcat4=\attribute23
\ltj@kcat5=\attribute24
\ltj@kcat6=\attribute25
Custom whatsit inhibitglue = 1
Custom whatsit stack_marker = 2
Custom whatsit begin_par = 3
Custom whatsit direction = 4
Custom whatsit box_boundary = 5
Custom whatsit ja_al_boundary = 6(load cache: ltj-cid-auto-adobe-japan1.luc)
Lua module: luatexja.charrange 2020-07-30 Handling the range of Japanese charact
ers
Lua module: luatexja.stack 2020-07-30 LuaTeX-ja stack system
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 2 in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `vpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.lineskip' at position 3 in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.lineskip' at position 1 in `append_to_vlist_filter'.
Lua module: luatexja.jfont 2021-11-06 Loader for Japanese fonts
Removing  `luaotfload.define_font' from `define_font'.
Inserting `luatexja.font_callback' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 7 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_font'.(load
 cache: extra_lmroman10-regular.luc)
Inserting `ltj.get_vert_form' at position 1 in `luatexja.define_jfont'.
Removing  `ltj.prepare_extra_data' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Removing  `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' from `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.supply_tounicode' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `ltj.prepare_extra_data' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 7 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 8 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
Inserting `ltj.process_input_buffer' at position 1 in `process_input_buffer'.
Inserting `ltj.hyphenate' at position 1 in `hyphenate'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Lua module: luatexja.jfmglue 2022-02-09 Insertion process of JFM glues, [x]kanji
skip and others
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.whatsit
_getinfo'.
Inserting `luatexja.beginpar.np_info_after' at position 1 in `luatexja.jfmglue.w
hatsit_after'.
Inserting `ltj.mlist_to_hlist_pre' at position 1 in `pre_mlist_to_hlist_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 5 in `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.set_stack_level' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.main' from `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' at position 2 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' at position 4 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.set_stack_level' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.node_processor' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.main' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' from `hpack_filter'.
Removing  `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' from `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.adjust_icflag' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.set_stack_level' at position 2 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 3 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.main' at position 4 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' at position 5 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `ltj.create_dir_whatsit' at position 6 in `hpack_filter'.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.sty"
Package: ltj-base 2021-03-16
\ltj@tempcntb=\count194
\ltj@tempcntc=\count195
\ltj@tempdima=\dimen142
\ltj@afbox=\box53
)
\ltj@@italic@inner=\luafunction14
\ltj@@start@time@measure@inner=\luafunction15
\ltj@@stop@time@measure@inner=\luafunction16
\ltj@@jfont@inner=\luafunction17
\ltj@zw@inner=\luafunction18
\ltj@zh@inner=\luafunction19
\ltj@reset@globaldefs@inner=\luafunction20
\ltj@restore@globaldefs@inner=\luafunction21
\ltj@@disihb@inner=\luafunction22
\ltj@@ihb@inner=\luafunction23
\ltj@@fakeparbegin@inner=\luafunction24
\ltj@@fakeboxbdd@inner=\luafunction25
\ltj@@ins@xk@inner=\luafunction26
\ltj@@ins@k@inner=\luafunction27
\ltj@@stack=\count196
\ltj@@group@level=\count197
\ltjsetkanjiskip@inner=\luafunction28
\ltjsetxkanjiskip@inner=\luafunction29
\ltj@@getparam@one@inner=\luafunction30
\ltj@alljachar@inner=\luafunction31
\ltj@@lua@populate@insertwhatsit@inner=\luafunction32
\ltj@@vadjust@begin@inner=\luafunction33
\ltj@@vadjust@dirhook@inner=\luafunction34
\ltj@@vadjust@check@dir@inner=\luafunction35
\ltj@@box@dirhook@inner=\luafunction36
\ltj@@reset@badness@inner=\luafunction37
\ltj@@lua@raisebox@inner=\luafunction38
\ltj@@lua@unboxcheckdir@inner=\luafunction39
(load cache: ltj-kinsoku_default.luc)(load cache: ltj-kinsoku_default.lua.gz)C:/
Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.lua:302: bad argument #1 to 'l
oadstring' (function expected, got no value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'loadstring'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.lua:302: in upvalue 'load_
cache_a'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-base.lua:323: in field 'load_ca
che'
    C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja.lua:387: in field 'load_ki
nsoku'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.776 \directlua{luatexja.load_kinsoku()}
                                       
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-latex.sty"
Package: ltj-latex 2021-10-24 LaTeX support of LuaTeX-ja
Inserting `ltj.direction' at position 1 in `pre_shipout_filter'.
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjfont.sty"
Package: lltjfont 2021-05-26 Patch to NFSS2 for LuaTeX-ja
\ltj@@latex@plv=\count198

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def"
File: tuenc.def 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX file
\@remove@tlig@@@@=\luafunction40
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 106.
)
\Cht=\dimen143
\cht=\dimen144
\Cdp=\dimen145
\cdp=\dimen146
\Cwd=\dimen147
\cwd=\dimen148
\Cvs=\dimen149
\cvs=\dimen150
\Chs=\dimen151
\chs=\dimen152
\cHT=\dimen153
\dstrutbox=\box54
\tstrutbox=\box55
\zstrutbox=\box56
LaTeX Info: Redefining \strut on input line 91.
\ltj@@add@fenc@@inner=\luafunction41
\ltj@@add@kyenc@@inner=\luafunction42
\ltj@@add@ktenc@@inner=\luafunction43
\ltj@@is@kyenc@@inner=\luafunction44
\ltj@@is@ktenc@@inner=\luafunction45
\ltj@@is@kenc@@inner=\luafunction46
\ltj@@is@ffam@@inner=\luafunction47
\ltj@@add@ffam@@inner=\luafunction48
\ltj@@add@kfam@@inner=\luafunction49
\ltj@@adjust@baseline@inner=\luafunction50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontencoding on input line 645.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontfamily on input line 688.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontseries on input line 922.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontseriesforce on input line 923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontshape on input line 943.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \fontshapeforce on input line 954.
\ltj@@jfont@@jfmonly@@inner=\luafunction51
\ltj@@does@alt@set@@inner=\luafunction52
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjdefs.sty"
Package: lltjdefs 2022-01-23 Default font settings of LuaTeX-ja
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 75.

(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujisv.lua)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 75.
(load cache: extra_haranoajimincho-regular.luc)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/jfm-ujis.lua)
warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.75 \kanjiencoding{JY3}\selectfont
                                 \adjustbaseline
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.75 \kanjiencoding{JY3}\selectfont
                                 \adjustbaseline
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.75 \kanjiencoding{JY3}\selectfont
                                 \adjustbaseline
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.75 \kanjiencoding{JY3}\selectfont
                                 \adjustbaseline
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

\symmincho=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `mincho' in version `bold'
(Font)                  JY3/mc/m/n --> JY3/gt/m/n on input line 84.
) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjcore.sty"
Package: lltjcore 2022-01-17 Patch to LaTeX2e Kernel for LuaTeX-ja
\@tombowwidth=\dimen154
\@TL=\box57
\@Tl=\box58
\@TC=\box59
\@TR=\box60
\@Tr=\box61
\@BL=\box62
\@Bl=\box63
\@BC=\box64
\@BR=\box65
\@Br=\box66
\@CL=\box67
\@CR=\box68
(load cache: extra_lmmono9-regular.luc)
\@bannertoken=\toks26
\@@paperheight=\dimen155
\@@paperwidth=\dimen156
\@@topmargin=\dimen157
LaTeX Info: Redefining \underline on input line 261.
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-atbegshi.sty"
Package: lltjp-atbegshi 2021-04-29 Patching \shipout hooks for LuaTeX-ja
\l__platex_shipout_dummy_box=\box69
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/patches/lltjp-geometry.sty"
Package: lltjp-geometry 2021-10-24 Patch to geometry for LuaTeX-ja with vertica
l writing mode

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)))
\ltj@temp@cctb=\catcodetable14
)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/luatexja-compat.sty"
Package: luatexja-compat 2020-08-08 Compatibility with pTeX
(load cache: ltj-jisx0208.luc)
\hour=\count199
\minute=\count266
))(load cache: extra_lmroman17-regular.luc)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 15.39551pt on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 15.39551pt on input line 16.

warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.16 }
    
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.16 }
    
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.16 }
    
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.16 }
    
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2021-08-27 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: fontspec 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2020/02/21 2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty"
Package: fontspec-luatex 2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count267
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count268
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count269
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count270
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count271
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count272
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count273
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count274
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count275
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count276
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count277
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen158
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen159
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen160

("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.6222pt on input line 112.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JT3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 479.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `JY3/mc/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.53629pt on input line 479.

warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.479 ...if_in:NnT \@filelist {.cls} { \normalsize }
                                                  
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hpack filter): error: C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/luatex/luatexja/ltj-
stack.lua:128: attempt to index a nil value (field 'table_current_stack')

.
<to be read again> 
\ltj@@reset@badness 
l.479 ...if_in:NnT \@filelist {.cls} { \normalsize }
                                                  
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.
```

If I comment out the luatexja package, it works fine but doesn't show the Chinese characters.

I tried to compile the same document with xelatex and xeCJK and it shows the characters, so I guess the fonts should be installed? Unfortunately, I can't use xelatex since my institution wants me to use lualatex for this document.

Does anybody have an idea what this problem might be? I would be happy if somebody could help me.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with TeX Live 2021 or TeX Live 2022. But many of your packages look rather old, you might want to try to update everything.

Comment: works fine for me on a current miktex. My luaotfload version there is luaotfload 2022-02-27 3.20

Comment: Ok, thanks for that hint. I used MiKTeX Console to update my packages, now I have MikTex 22.3, LuaHBTex 1.15.0 and luaotfload version 2022-03-18 3.21. I still get the same errors.

Do you have any ideas on how I could find out more?

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround. I found out the institution does accept xelatex, so I'll just use this for now. In case anyone knows this problem with lualatex, I'd still be happy to hear your idea